# Serilog not logging when published ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1, serilog

I have Serilog configured to write to both an MSSQL table and to a File (to try and determine whats happening.) on a WebApi with ASP.NET core (running Core 2.1).

I add the Serilog logging in my `startup.cs` as follows;

```
public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
        .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
            DbGlobals.DevDatabase, "Logs", schemaName:DbGlobals.SchemaName)
        .WriteTo.File("Logs\\Serilog\\log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
        .CreateLogger();

    loggerFactory.AddSerilog(log);
```

where `DbGlobals.DevDatbase` and `Dbglobals.SchemaName` are string read from the configuration.

UPDATE For reference these values are;

```
DbGlobals.Schema = "MySchema";
DbGlobals.DevDatabase = "Data Source=xx.xx.xx.xx;Initial Catalog=DevDatabase;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=LOGIN;Password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;";
```

When running locally with IIS Express and under both `debug` and `release` configurations, both logging functions are working correctly. So for example in my controller;

```
public class ReviewPublicController : Controller
{
    private readonly IReviewService _service;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IMailService _mailService;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public ReviewController(
        IReviewService service, 
        ILogger<ReviewController> logger)
    {
        _service = service;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Review), 201)]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]ReviewPostModel model)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Posting Review");

        ...

        return Ok();
    }
```

So locally "Posting Review" is written to both my File and DbSchema.

However, when I publish to my server, the above "Posting Review" entry is not written to either.

Both appear to be working as information entries are being added from EF and routing etc but not when I specifically try to write an entry?

Can anyone direct me here as to what the issue could be please?

The current nuget versions are;

```
Serilog 2.7.1
Serilog.AspNetCore 2.1.1
Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer 5.1.2
Serilog.Sinks.File 4.0.0
```

Also, I have the following in my `appsettings.json`;

```
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Release": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
```

Comment: please share `DbGlobals.DevDatabase`

Comment: Do you have any appsetting.json for serilog?

Comment: ok I have updated although not sure the relevance as I can confim it connects to the database. It also writes to the file just not my logging output

Comment: @Stefan There is the default logging sections in the `appsettings.json` but (unless i am wrong) from the above it doesn't take these into account? (this was my next step once I could confirm the logging worked correctly). I'll add that now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*update*

As in the docs:

> Default Level - if no MinimumLevel is specified, then Information level events and higher will be processed.

So basically, it seems that your configuration is either invalid or overwritten. see: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics

---

`LogDebug` is disabled by default in a `Release` build, which is probably what your publish is.

Please try with

```
_logger.LogInformation("Posting Review");
```

Comment: sound promising I'll give it a shot now.

Comment: That worked, I can confirm that both `LogInformation` and `LogError` worked when publishing. The odd thing was that it worked under a release build locally, and I thought that `LogDebug` would just be part of the logging heirarchy? Do you know why this is not the case? (out of interest)

Comment: That's interesting, I was always under the view that this was controlled by the logging configuration settings.

Comment: Hmm, you are right about that, as in the docs: `Default Level - if no MinimumLevel is specified, then Information level events and higher will be processed.`. So basically, it seems that your configuration is either invalid or overwritten. see: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics

Comment: yes, these are the docs I followed. this is why I used `.MinimumLevel.Verbose()` like you say perhaps WebDeploy causes a change??

Answer (score 1):

For me what was the solution is to remove the `"restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"` from `appsettings.json`.

It was exactly the same in `appsettings.Development.json` and it was working well in Development environment.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have configured all above. It logs db in my local environment, where as it does not work in dev environment. The issue is due to authentication. I am using azure ad authentication for my application that restricts serilog to write into server. So, In my program.cs file, I have added the below settings.

> Program.cs

```
var sqlSinkOptions = new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
{
      TableName = "MyLogTableName",
      UseAzureManagedIdentity = true,  // This line
      AzureServiceTokenProviderResource = "https://database.windows.net/" // This line
};
```

After that, I can see logging is happening in dev environment too. May be this helps some one. Happy coding!